# Errors with mysqli php secure login script

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

I have searched google, read in the PHP manual and tried several tutorials to make a secure login script for mysqli and PHP. Does anyone know of one that actually works without `md5`?

I would like to see some working code or a tutorial if possible.

Mine won't actually query the db or return a value, even after hardcoding the values into the script... I'm looking for something like:

- connect using the 'connectdb' file
- post the user/pwd from the form
- query db for user/pwd
- set session with username
- etc.

This is my code that doesn't work:

```
<?php

include ("conectionlink.php");

//connection errors if any...

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$userid = htmlentities($_POST['userid'], ENT_QUOTES);
$password = htmlentities($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES);


//create a prepared statement

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT userid, password FROM admins WHERE userid=? and password=?")) {



// bind parameters-define them...
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $userid, $password);


//execute...
    $stmt->execute();

    // bind result variables 
    $stmt->bind_result($userid,$password)



//fetch value
    $stmt->fetch();

 var_dump($userid, $password);
 printf("%n is associated with %s", $userid, $password);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

I receive the following error message:

Comment: What as usually do is storing passwords in mysql DB using MD5(password) and then, at login page, compare md5 user password input with md5 password from DB (regarding the username provided)

Comment: I believe the `bind_result()` syntax would be like this: `bind_result($userid,$password)`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-result-examples

Comment: the "is" is to indicate integer, string in those cells...thanks...

Comment: tried it without the "is" in the bind result, same error...error indicates on this line/lines:      // bind result variables 
    $stmt->bind_result($userid);
    $stmt->bind_result($password);

Comment: @user3000619 showdev says try to make your bind_result on line `bind_result($userid,$password)`. Dont alter this `$stmt->bind_param("is", $userid, $password);` it's working

Comment: could you explain more...

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in line 31 an 36 when i do that...

Comment: only line 35,36 sorry...which is //fetch value
    $stmt->fetch();

Comment: Please edit your question and add your new code so we can see what you've changed.

Comment: Looks good. You just need a semicolon after your bind statement: `$stmt->bind_result($userid,$password);`

Comment: but it prints this out and doesn't actually pull the value from the db... int(0) string(0) "" is associated with...it should output 'the username whatever' is associated with 'the password whatever'...based on the query

Answer (score 2):

According to the [PHP documentation for mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-result-examples), `bind_result()` syntax should be in one line, rather than performing multiple binds:

```
bind_result ( mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )
```

So, instead of this:

```
$stmt->bind_result($userid);
$stmt->bind_result($password);
```

try doing this:

```
$stmt->bind_result($userid,$password);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be treating the `userid` column as containing an integer, when I suspect you are really receiving a string.  You initialize `$userid` like this:

```
$userid = htmlentities($_POST['userid'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Then you use it in a `SELECT` and treat it as an integer in your `bind_param()` call.  So, you're treating it like an integer (which seems unlikely in a `$_POST` variable -- I expect you are really receiving a string username, not an integer ID).

You also have a problem with your call to `printf()` -- `%n` is not a recognized format.  You can see the acceptable formats at the [`sprintf()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

In short, I suspect you are using the wrong column in your `SELECT` statement, and that it is actually supposed to be something like `username`.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding; you are trying to access an integer column, but then acting as if it will return a user name, rather than a numeric id.  Something is wrong with your logic.  But you haven't told us how your table is defined, so we can't help you.

Comment: userid is an 8 digit integer
username is text
password is text (for now)

Comment: Exactly my point: is the user typing the username, or their userid? I'm pretty sure it's the former, in which case your SQL logic is wrong (and your variable names are confusing you).

Comment: P.S. Don't store your passwords without hashing! That is extremely unsafe.