# mysqli query and session

Tags: php, session, mysqli

This is designed to help me understand what is going on with the query.

It should tell me what values are queried and print them.

It does not pull the userid for some reason, instead saying 0 or null.

It prints:

```
string(0) "" NULL string(11) "pwdhere" The userid is 0 and the password is pwdhere----oooo set as oooo----6179cbcdc21dd1b3c478e7e2226e0432
```

Should the session be these 32 characters or the userid/username?

Why is it not pulling userid?

AND WHY DOES IT WORK WHEN THE PASSWORD IS WRONG?

THANKS!!!

```
<?php
    //Store the login in the session:
      session_start();

?>
    <?php

    include ("connectionlinkhere.php");

    //connection errors if any...

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    //GETTING DATA FROM FORM

    $userid = htmlentities($_POST['userid'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $password = htmlentities($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES);


    //create a prepared statement

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT userid, username, password FROM admins WHERE userid=? and password=?"))

     { 

    // bind parameters-define them...the -iss- is for integer, string, string
        $stmt->bind_param("iss", $userid, $username, $password);

    //execute...
        $stmt->execute();

        // bind result variables 
        $stmt->bind_result($userid, $username, $password);

    //fetch value
        $stmt->fetch();

//to see what the database query is actually pulling
    var_dump($userid, $username, $password);

//tell it to format the query results and then print the sentence
    $format = 'The userid is %d and the password is %s';
    echo sprintf($format, $userid, $password);

//set session
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $_POST['username'];

//just to break up the line   
 echo "----oooo set as oooo----" ;
//this is the 32 digit session value, although assigned as userid or username
    echo session_id();




        /* close statement */
        $stmt->close();
    }


     // redirect the user
          //header("Location: index.php");

          else
          {
          echo "what are you doing...";
          }

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: please don't store passwords as pain text.

Comment: when I go live I won't but wanted to make sure hashing wasn't the issue as I develop this page.  thanks though

Comment: I can't upvote @Dagon's comment enough. Are you using `bind_param` for three entries, but only having two `?` in the statement?

Comment: yes because I only call two in the form, I pull the third from the query...

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109690/errors-with-mysqli-php-secure-login-script/20110118#20110118). Please don't duplicate posts.  Have you tried everything in the answers and comments on that question? People are trying to help you there!

Comment: I thought it had been marked answered...sorry

Comment: "I pull the third from the query": That is *not* how `bind_param()` works.

Comment: I was trying to bind all the params from the query...I can't very well declare it earlier than that, right?  I'm trying to bind all the data the comes out of the query for use in the session, etc.

Comment: `bind_param()` binds variables to placeholders (the `?`) -- it has nothing to do with what you get out of the query.

Comment: userid is an integer, username and password are strings.  the login form only allows userid and pwd...the username has to come from the query...suggestions?  and i tried to put an else statement in for when the pwd is incorrect but can't successfully do that.  also the vardump is printing out 0 or null...indicating a problem there... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You use `bind_param()` to replace `?` in your query with what you are looking for. You use `bind_result()` to get the data from your query (which you have done correctly, from what I can see). Put the data you want to search for in `bind_param()` to replace the `?`'s.

Was writing a comment, then realized this may be the issue... Thank you @EdCottrell.